# How do i add some more data to recently viewed products in magento?

Tags: magento

I would like to add some additional information to my recently viewed products section like product image+some additional information...

could someone help me to know how this recently viewed products section works, or how magento places data in recently viewed products.?

Thank you very much..!!!

Comment: I had did it... i used a session to store the product attributes.. and retrieve it in the recently viewed section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for the problem, i used a session to store the product attributes.. and retrieve it in the recently viewed section

Comment: thanks for moving your comment to a real answer. Already delete-voted the community wiki answer as it's obsolete now.